Roslyn SemanticModel does not contain the static constructor generated for const decimal initialization
Before I open an issue for the Roslyn folks I would like to understand better the situation. I have learned that const decimals are not really consts, but statics and a hence the static constructor is created implicitly to initialize them.
However, the respective Roslyn SemanticModel instance does not report any symbol for it. Unlike other cases when the static constructor is also implicitly created. E.g. for proper static field initialization.
Here is an example code using Roslyn and Mono.Cecil and NUnit as the runner:
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp;
using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Syntax;
using Mono.Cecil;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace CSTool.UnitTests;

public class RoslynScratch
{
    private const string CODE = @"public static class Type1
{
    public const decimal Value = 1.0m;
}
public static class Type2
{
    public static readonly decimal Value = 1.0m;
}
public static class Type3
{
    public const int Value = 1;
}";
    private static readonly string[] s_netCoreReferences =
    [
        typeof(object).Assembly.Location,
        Path.GetDirectoryName(typeof(object).Assembly.Location) + "\\System.Runtime.dll",
    ];

    [Test]
    public void StaticCtor()
    {
        var syntaxTree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(CODE);
        var compilation = CSharpCompilation.Create("temp", [syntaxTree],
            s_netCoreReferences.Select(o => MetadataReference.CreateFromFile(o)).ToArray(),
            new CSharpCompilationOptions(OutputKind.NetModule));
        Assert.That(compilation.GetDiagnostics(), Is.Empty);
        var model = compilation.GetSemanticModel(syntaxTree);
        var typeDecls = syntaxTree.GetRoot().DescendantNodes().OfType<ClassDeclarationSyntax>().ToList();
        Assert.That(typeDecls, Has.Count.EqualTo(3));
        AssertStaticCtor(model, typeDecls, "Type1", false);
        AssertStaticCtor(model, typeDecls, "Type2", true);
        AssertStaticCtor(model, typeDecls, "Type3", false);

        var ms = new MemoryStream();
        var emitResult = compilation.Emit(ms);
        Assert.That(emitResult.Success, Is.True);
        Assert.That(emitResult.Diagnostics, Is.Empty);
        ms.Position = 0;
        var moduleDef = ModuleDefinition.ReadModule(ms, new ReaderParameters
        {
            InMemory = true,
        });
        AssertStaticCtor(moduleDef, "Type1", true);
        AssertStaticCtor(moduleDef, "Type2", true);
        AssertStaticCtor(moduleDef, "Type3", false);
    }

    private void AssertStaticCtor(ModuleDefinition moduleDef, string typeName, bool expected)
    {
        var staticCtorDef = moduleDef.GetType(typeName).Methods.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == ".cctor");
        Assert.That(staticCtorDef, expected ? Is.Not.Null : Is.Null);
    }

    private static void AssertStaticCtor(SemanticModel model, IList<ClassDeclarationSyntax> typeDecls, string typeName, bool expected)
    {
        var typeSymbol = model.GetDeclaredSymbol(typeDecls.First(o => o.Identifier.Text == typeName));
        var staticCtorSymbol = typeSymbol.GetMembers().FirstOrDefault(o => o.Name == ".cctor");
        Assert.That(staticCtorSymbol, expected ? Is.Not.Null : Is.Null);
    }
}

Compare the assertions for the Roslyn's SemanticModel vs Mono.Cecil's ModuleDefinition:
Roslyn
        AssertStaticCtor(model, typeDecls, "Type1", false);
        AssertStaticCtor(model, typeDecls, "Type2", true);
        AssertStaticCtor(model, typeDecls, "Type3", false);

Mono.Cecil
        AssertStaticCtor(moduleDef, "Type1", true);
        AssertStaticCtor(moduleDef, "Type2", true);
        AssertStaticCtor(moduleDef, "Type3", false);

The code asserts that Roslyn does NOT report any symbol for the static constructor in the case in question, but the Mono.Cecil does, as expected, since it is really there.
The other two assertions emphasize the special nature of this particular case, because Roslyn and Mono.Cecil disagree with each other only in this case.
So what am I missing? Is it by design or is it a bug that I should report?
P.S.
I found one more case when Roslyn does not report a symbol where there is actually a method. It is not related to static constructor at all. This happens in the following scenario:
public class Derived: BaseImplementingInterfaceMethods, IInterface
{
}

Here BaseImplementingInterfaceMethods implements all the methods of IInterface without formally implementing the interface itself. The compiler injects implicitly explicit implementation of the interface to Derived which just delegate to BaseImplementingInterfaceMethods. These methods are not reported by Roslyn as well.
But this is off topic.
